# Debug external library with qtcreator: navigate with debugger in sources instead assembler

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, qt-creator, ide-customization

I have CMake project in qtcreator and live555 opensource library imported with conan package manager.  Qtcreator's debugger show me this error: [live555 crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gMXP.png)

I want to navigate inside live555's source code with debugger like i do on my own code, but debugger show me just assembler listing instead. Also, i can see full stack in debugger. This indicates that the library was built with debug symbols.

Platform info: ubuntu, gcc, gdb as qtcreator's debugger.

It looks like i should point debugger to live555 source code location but i dont know how it should be done.

I tried add 'directory /home/user/live' to ~/.gdbinit but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try add library source path in Tools > Options > Debugger > General Table "Source Paths Mapping" in QtCreator.

But are you sure that you know exact version of sources (git commit hash) for your binaries?

Upd. From [qtcreator doc](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-preferences.html#mapping-source-paths):

- In the Source path field, specify the source path in the debug information of the executable as reported by the debugger.
- In the Source path field, specify the source path in the debug information of the executable as reported by the debugger.

Comment: Certainly, i have exact source code of .so library since it have been build from source code with conan locally. "Source Paths Mapping" in QtCreator feature require source path and target path. I have a source path (it is path to source) but i have no target path (path to .so file dont work).